# how to add yocto recipy that will be build for non-default target arch

Tags: makefile, yocto-recipe

I work for a large yocto based project which builds has a target that builds the firmware for an embedded ARM device.

One of the recipes downloads the source code and builds a component by running a "make " command in do_compile(). The compilation will use the arm toolchain internally and produce an executable for the ARM arch.

For that  specific component a different "make <host_tool>" target can build a host tool that is useful when debugging binary logs obtained from the target.

The objective here is to build the "host_tool" during the bitbake process. I am not sure who should the recipy file look in such a case. Should the "MACHINE" variable be overwritten locally in that recipy file ? Should I create a completely new layer when there MACHINE for that recipy be included there ? Should I create a completely new "bitbake " target ? If the latter is the correct approach where should I place my recipy in that case ?

Thank you in advance for your help